# Woocommerce - Billing Details onchange hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a plugin for Woocommerce and I need something I don't know if it's posible:

I need to know if there is a hook that fires when Billing Details checkout change.

I need to do a call to an API when the Postcode/Zip change having it's value to pase it as an argument to the API.

Something like:

```
do_action('hook_fired_when_billing_input_change', array($this, 'my_function'));

function my_function($billingData) {    
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: When the billing address changes on the front end (during checkout) that won't trigger a server-side action. But you could catch the change with javascript and then send an ajax request to your API.

Comment: Thhanks @helgatheviking. I found some trick that do what i want (don't know if is the best way):

There is a hook named 'woocommerce_package_rates' triggered every time Checkout's order info is rendered and if you change something in Billing details is triggered.

As I want to activate or not a shipping method depending on postal code it works for me.